# DPDK: What are the typical causes of q_errors in rte_eth_stats structure?

Tags: udp, dpdk

### Background

This question is regarding an application that uses DPDK to process incoming UDP packets. I am trying to get as close to lossless transmission as possible, but still seeing small amounts of packet loss. The packets are transmitted directly from one computer to another with no switch between the two, so I expect to have minimal to no packet loss.

### What I know

According to the results of `rte_eth_stats_get(rte_eth_stats *stats)`, the lost packets are completely attributed to q_errors. According to the [DPDK Documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__eth__stats.html), **q_errors** denotes the "Total number of queue packets received that are dropped", as opposed to **ierrors**, which denotes the "Total number of erroneous received packets".

### What I would like to know

Does anyone know what some typical causes of **q_errors** may be that are more specific than the DPDK documentation? Maybe this packet loss is inevitable due to the nature of UDP, but I would like to know where to look for problems in case the packet loss is not inevitable.

Comment: Do both ends have DPDK application? If so what are those? Please share more details.